# How do I change the stacking order of objects in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my projects when I forget to add something in the Main Storyboard, I always have to redo the entire thing if I want to change the "layer order." For example, if I want to add an Image View (with full screen constraints) as the background after I've already some other elements, it will cover them. How do I change the "layer" that each element is on without deleting and remaking them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the element you want to arrange, hit **Editor > Arrange > Send to Back** (or send backward depending on how you want to arrange it)